# Voltage drop and voltage rise

Tags: electrostatics, potential, voltage

Is the voltage drop the negative of the standard voltage (or potential difference)?

[image]

Usually we indicate the potential difference with an arrow pointing against the direction of the electric field, i.e. where the field decreases, there the potential increases. In a circuit, instead, the arrow for the votage drop seems to point in the direction of voltage decrease, and in fact the voltage $V_b-V_a$ is negative. However, we talk of *positive* voltage drop. So, am I right assuming that

$-\Delta{V}=$ voltage drop?

Thanks!

Comment: The word "drop" is meant to mean "decrease".

Comment: @garyp so is it $-\Delta{V}=$?

Comment: It's up to you.  It's either voltage drop or change in potential.  In ether case you have to decide the sense (up or down) of your definition and let the reader know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Usually we indicate the potential difference with an arrow pointing
>   against the direction of the electric field, i.e. where the field
>   decreases, there the potential increases.

Potential difference (voltage) is not usually shown as an arrow. Usually you label one terminal positive and one terminal minus. The assignment plus to minus is by convention in the direction of assumed current flow (the flow of positive charge).

Based on the direction shown for current, in your diagram terminal $a$ would be labeled positive and terminal $b$ negative, meaning terminal $a$ is considered high potential and terminal $b$ low potential. There is then a decrease in electrical potential (voltage) in going from terminal $a$ to terminal $b$.

The electric field by convention is directed plus to minus, the direction of the force that a positive charge would experience if placed in the field. So the electric field points from $a$ to $b$.

> In a circuit, instead, the arrow for the votage drop seems to point in
>   the direction of voltage decrease

Yes the direction of the arrow is the direction of a decrease in potential (decrease in potential). That is consistent.

> and in fact the voltage − is negative. However, we talk of
>   positive voltage drop. So, am I right assuming that
>
> −Δ= voltage drop?

This is a bit confusing. Not sure what you mean by a "positive voltage drop".

Whether there is a voltage rise or a voltage drop across a component really depends on the direction assumed for current flow in your analysis. Based on the assumed direction of current flow in your diagram, there is a voltage drop, or decrease in potential, going from $a$ to $b$. If the current was shown in the opposite direction, the polarities would be reversed and you would have a voltage rise, or increase, going from $a$ to $b$. After doing an analysis of the circuit (e.g., loop analysis), if you get a negative value for current, the true direction is simply the opposite of that assumed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, that really helps a lot! In the last part I mean, how do we calculare the voltage drop,  with minus the integral from b to a (in the above diagram) of the electric field times the differential of displacement? Which value should I expect after evaluating the drop, postive or negative? Thanks again!

Comment: @Shootforthemoon If the resistance is uniform between the terminals of the resistor, the voltage drop produces a uniform electric field throughout that depends on the length of the resistive material. Since $E$ is a constant in the resistor, it comes out of the integral and we get the voltage drop of $V=EL$ where $L$ is the length of the resistor and is positive going from $a$ to $b$ in your diagram.

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot!